# Java 8 optional map and execute different functions

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

What should be the Java 8 equivalent of

```
if ( indicator != null ){
   return getTest(a,indicator);
else{
   return getTest(a);
}
```

if `indicator` is to be an `Optional` instead of nullable?

Comment: Why do you think that the java 8 code should look any different from this?

Comment: what's `indicator`, what's `getTest` method signature? what's the context?

Comment: indicator is an Optional  Boolean variable. And getTest() is a method in the code. I'm trying to use lambda to remove this if-else condition.

Comment: Why don't you just handle the nullity of `indicator` inside `getTest`?

Comment: Ask 10 people, get 11 answers...

Comment: @rdas there is a nullable value, I think he want to use `Optional` instead explicit `if`

Comment: the existing of `Optional` and Java 8 futures, doesn't mean to avoid using `if..else` :)

Comment: @YCF_L not, but he is asking for

Comment: sorry @josejuan I don't get you

Comment: @YCF_L _"doesn't mean to avoid"_ yes, but he said: _"I'm trying to use lambda to remove this if-else condition"_

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

**Java**

```
Optional<Boolean> indicator = ...;
return indicator.map(i -> getTest(a, i)).orElseGet(() -> getTest(a));
```

But not always is `Optional` better than simple `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably provoking answer but the Java 8 version of :

```
if (indicator != null){
   return getTest(a,indicator);
}
else{
   return getTest(a);
}
```

is the same thing :

```
if (indicator != null){
   return getTest(a,indicator);
}
else{
   return getTest(a);
}
```

And in fact I would probably use that more terse way :

```
if (indicator != null){
   return getTest(a,indicator);
}
return getTest(a);
```

In your case, using `Optional` with "chaining" methods such as :

```
return indicator.map(i -> getTest(a, i)).orElseGet(() -> getTest(a));
```

hides the flow logic while your actual code shows that perfectly: you have two distinct cases. In a general way, you want to chain processings/transformations but you don't want to chain forking scenarios since these are different scenarios.
If you want to use `Optional` to convey the fact that this object may be `null`, which is perfectly legitimate, I would probably do something that mimics the `if-else` logic that is clear :

```
Optional<Indicator> optIndicator = findIndicator();
if (indicator.isPresent()){
   return getTest(a,indicator.get());
}
return getTest(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write:

No time complexity and space.

```
Optional<Boolean> indicator = ...;
    if(indicator.isPresent()) {
        // value is present inside Optional
        return getTest(a,indicator);
    } else {
        // value is absent
      return getTest(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it simply:

```
boolean indicator = ...;
return indicator ?  getTest(a, i) : getTest(a);
```

Or

```
Optional<Boolean> indicator = ...;
return indicator.orElse(false) ?  getTest(a, i) : getTest(a);
```